# Making a Python program handle mailto links

Tags: python, email, parsing, mailto

I made a Python program that is capable of sending email. However, I want to make it capable of being a default email client such that it will capture the email address and subject of HTML email links (mailto links) when the user clicks them.

How do I get the email address and subject to my client?

Currently, I can set my program as the default mail client, but I don't know what information, or format of information, it's getting from the web browser; so, I'm not sure how to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the complete link is passed in as `sys.argv[1]`, you need to do something like this:

```
import urllib.parse
parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(sys.argv[1])
mail_addr = parsed.path
fields = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed.query)
```

This sets `mail_addr` to the address to send the email to, while `field` will be a dictionary of additional parameters.

The fields that you can expect to be present are specified in [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068)